# jQuery Find and replace with contents of a div

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm looking to find and replace text with jQuery, but found only simple functions that replaced static text with other static text. I wanted to figure out how to replace a string with the contents of another div. For Example:

```
<div class="item-one">blue</div>

<p>My color is item one</p>
```

What i want to do is replace the string "item one" with the contents of the div with a class of item-one. I want not just one instance of this string, but all of them on the page. I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text` method:

```
$('p').text(function(i, current){
   var c = $('.item-one').text();
   return current.replace('item one', c);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3eE4G/

In case that you have more elements:

```
$('p').text(function(i, t) {
   var w = t.split(' ')[4];
   var c = $('.item-'+w).text();
   return t.replace('item '+w, c)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e7DRr/

Comment: Beautiful. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').text($('p').text().replace('item one',$('.item-one').text()));
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sRYWe/).

Tips:

- If 'item-one' is unique use `ID` instead of class
- You should also add an unique id to the `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Trere two ways

First is to use .replace() function that can replace some static text to text from div like that:

```
$("p").text($("p").text().replace("text", $("#some_text").text()));
```

but better way is to take text what you want to change to "span" tag and use the text() function

```
$("p span").text($(".item-one").text());
```

Comment: Your script does nothing, as the changed value of the text is not being saved.

Comment: yes, in 1 function I made mistake, here is working version http://jsfiddle.net/BdnPJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have this fully dynamic, not caring about how many classes a div has, and how many times the div's content should be used.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var replaceClasses = [];
    var currentClasses;
    var i = 0;

    // Save all classes to be used for replacement in an array
    $('div').each(function()
    {
        currentClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        for (i; i < currentClasses.length; i++)
        {
            replaceClasses.push(currentClasses[i].replace('-', ' '));
        }
        i = 0;
    });

    // Loop all classes and replace text if applicable
    for (i; i < replaceClasses.length; i++)
    {
        var pText = $('p:contains("' + replaceClasses[i] + '")').text();

        $('p:contains("' + replaceClasses[i] + '")').each(function()
        {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(replaceClasses[i], $('.' + replaceClasses[i].replace(' ', '-')).text()));
        });
    }  

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzCCQ/